# Fitting a polynomial to chunks of a large CMIP6 NetCDF xarray?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, chunks, numpy-ufunc

My goal is to calculate a quadratic fit over the time-dimension of 'zos' (sea level) data of piControl runs of various CMIP6 models and subtract that from other runs. In this particular example, the data looks as follows:

```
Out[108]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (bnds: 2, ncells: 830305, time: 3, vertices: 16)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) object 2401-01-16 12:00:00 ... 2401-03-16 12:00:00
    lon        (ncells) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(5000,), meta=np.ndarray>
    lat        (ncells) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(5000,), meta=np.ndarray>
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds, ncells, vertices
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, bnds) object dask.array<chunksize=(3, 2), meta=np.ndarray>
    lon_bnds   (ncells, vertices) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(5000, 16), meta=np.ndarray>
    lat_bnds   (ncells, vertices) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(5000, 16), meta=np.ndarray>
    zos        (time, ncells) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(3, 5000), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I tried using *xarray.Dataset.polyfit()*, but this results in **AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'polyfit'**. Presumably this is because the CMIP6 models have irregular calendars and model years that are outside of the supported range (e.g., **'enable to decode time axis into full numpy.datetime64 objects, continuing using cftime.datetime objects instead, reason: dates out of range'**). This is also why I'm using *encode_times=False* in the snippet below.

Alternatively, I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960903/applying-numpy-polyfit-to-xarray-dataset):

```html
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval,polyfit
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

xr.set_options(display_style="html")  # fancy HTML repr

mycmip6 = (
    xr.open_dataset('/Volumes/Naamloos/PhD_Data/CMIP6/raw_mergetime/zos/AWI-CM-1-1-MR/zos_Omon_AWI-CM-1-1-MR_piControl_r1i1p1f1_gn_240101-290012.nc',decode_times=False,chunks={'ncells':5000})
    .isel(time=slice(3)) #using a small slice for example
    )
mycmip6

def fit_quadratic(data, time):
    pfit = np.polyfit(time, data,2) 
    
    return np.transpose( np.polyval(pfit,time) )


pfit = xr.apply_ufunc(
    fit_quadratic,  # first the function
    mycmip6.zos, #sea level data
    mycmip6.time,  # time
    input_core_dims=[["time"], ["time"]],  # list with one entry per arg
    output_core_dims=[["time"]],  # returned data has one dimension
    vectorize=True,  # loop over non-core dims
    dask="parallelized",
    output_dtypes=[mycmip6.zos.dtype],
)
```

This works fine, but as soon as I try to manipulate or save pfit to netcdf,

```
pfit.compute()
```

I run into this error:

```
TypeError: wrong number of positional arguments: expected 2, got 3
```

When I'm not using chunking at all, I can use 'pfit', but I run into memory issues for the largest datasets.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI `polyfit` was only recently merged and has not made into an xarray release yet (as of May 2nd, 2020), so that's my guess as to why you're getting an `AttributeError`.  Once a new release of xarray is made, however, `polyfit` will operate on Dataset objects and will work with `cftime.datetime` coordinates!

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime, I discovered things work for me when I change dask="parallelized" to dask="allowed".